# How to select elements from a List based on conditions on an analogous list?

Tags: list-manipulation

c and z are equal-sized lists.  Whichever elements in z meet a certain criterion, I want a list of the corresponding elements from c.  This is the clunky way I came up with:

```
c = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, 20];
z = Abs[(((c^2 + c)^2 + c)^2 + c)^2 + c];
keepc = {};
Do[
  If[z[[k]] <= 2, AppendTo[keepc, c[[k]]]], {k, 1, Length[c]}];
keepc
```

What would be the proper way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
res = Extract[c, Position[z, x_ /; x <= 2]]
```

{-0.50405 + 0.330151 I, -0.368681 - 0.326179 I, -0.522155 -
0.224775 I, -0.699138 + 0.648737 I, 0.290045 - 0.242275 I,
0.0816587 - 0.519248 I, -0.695207 + 0.130671 I, -0.561304 -
0.323975 I, 0.334523 + 0.352494 I, 0.3687 - 0.502679 I}

```
res == keepc
```

(* True *)

Or, the other way around,

```
MapAt[Nothing, c, Position[z, x_ /; x > 2]] == keepc
```

(* True *)

Also:

```
res = Select[c, Abs[(((#^2 + #)^2 + #)^2 + #)^2 + #] <= 2 &]

res == keepc
```

(* True *)

And, with the same result,

```
z = Abs[(((x^2 + x)^2 + x)^2 + x)^2 + x];

c /. x_ /; Evaluate[z > 2] :> Nothing
```

Comment: Success!  Thank you!  Goodness, Matlab has me spoiled with its simple syntax.  Too bad it does so little compared to Mathematica.

Answer (score 6):

```
Pick[c, UnitStep[2 - z], 1] == keepc
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Also

```
c[[PositionIndex[UnitStep[2 - z]] @ 1]] == keepc
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

**Using `Sow`/`Reap`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];
c = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, 20];
z = Abs[(((c^2 + c)^2 + c)^2 + c)^2 + c];

Scan[If[Last@# <= 2, Sow[First@#]] &, Transpose[{c, z}]] // Reap // 
  Last // First
```

> {-0.624394 + 0.424024 I, -0.517278 - 0.218836 I,
> 0.0844932 - 0.349297 I, -0.537691 + 0.18652 I, -0.207988 +
> 0.0375483 I,
> 0.400948 - 0.661974 I, -0.576348 - 0.0548697 I, -0.154299 -
> 0.976329 I, -0.50501 - 0.366248 I,
> 0.156112 - 0.0821956 I, -0.414261 - 0.0823102 I, -0.583898 +
> 0.455034 I}

`Append` is a slow operation and it is always preferable to `Sow`/`Reap` instead.

Comment: Ooooooh yeah, even not knowing the complete answer, I should have thought of using Sow/Reap.  Thanks.  I think you meant to say that Sow/Reap is preferable to Append.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Query` and `Select`:

```
c = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, 20];
z = Abs[(((c^2 + c)^2 + c)^2 + c)^2 + c];
keepc = Query[Select[#[[2]] <= 2 &], First]@Transpose[{c, z}];
res = Extract[c, Position[z, x_ /; x <= 2]];

keepc === res

(*True*)
```